# Inverse regex of compound interest

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

*Koronkorko* is the Finnish word for *compound interest*. We don't want compound interest in our strings, so let's find the shortest possible regular expression to exclude it.

Given a string consisting only of the uppercase alphabetic characters A-Z, determine the shortest possible regular expression that matches the string if it does not contain the substring `KORONKORKO`. Any string that contains `KORONKORKO` as a substring should not be matched by the regex.

Only the characters `A`-`Z`, `[`, `]`, `-`, `^`, , `?`, `*`, `+`, `|`, `(`, and `)` should be used in the expression.

I think this can be done with 118 characters in the expression. Can you make it shorter?

Note: This challenge is from [Ohjelmointiputka](http://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/postit/tehtava.php?tunnus=kala) (in Finnish).

Comment: If `!` was an allowed character, you could've done `^((?!KORONKORO).)*$` for 19 bytes.

Comment: @MamaFunRoll I think that's *why* `!` isn't allow.

Comment: I had the fun of trying to work my way around the Finnish site, and I believe what you're looking for are theoretical regex expressions which match/reject the input string. For example, the site only seems to allow the use of `-` and `^` inside character classes (so `^` can't be used as an anchor), and a match is only counted if the whole string is matched by the regex (i.e. an implicit surrounding `^$`, as opposed to normal "regexes" which count a string as matching if any part of it matches the regex)

Comment: As such I've deleted my PCRE answer which, while it should work even in PHP, is almost definitely unintended in this case.

Comment: I forgot to say that the site checks the if the expression is valid by PHP's ereg function. It was said in discussion in http://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/keskustelu/18785-putkaposti-29-k%C3%A4%C3%A4nteislauseke/sivu-1

Answer (score 6):

## 204 characters

```
(K((O(R(O(NKORO)*(NK(O(RK)?)?)?)?)?)?K)*(O(R(O(NKORO)*(N(K(O(RK?[^KO]|[^KR])|[^KO])|[^K])|[^KN])|[^KO])|[^KR])|[^KO])|[^K])*(K((O(R(O(NKORO)*(NK(O(RK)?)?)?)?)?)?K)*(O(R(O(NKORO)*(N(K(O(RK?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

Generated by turning `.*KORONKORKO.*` into a finite state machine, inverting the finite state machine, and turning it back into a regex.

Comment: Why did this become the best answer?

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>77</s> <s>79</s> <s>97</s> 118 bytes

**Edit 3:**  Rewrite. Uses nested lookaheads

```
^([^K]|K(?=$|[^O]|O(?=$|[^R]|R(?=$|[^O]|O(?=$|[^N]|N(?=$|[^K]|K(?=$|[^O]|O(?=$|[^R]|R(?=$|[^K]|K(?=$|[^O]))))))))))*$
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/kO7vM2/2)

**Edit 2:** Added '$|' throughout the regex. Now, if a prefix of KORONKORKO has been matched, the next item to match is end-of-string, a character that ends the prefix, or a character that extends the prefix if it is followed by something that ends the prefix.

This regex works with `re.fullmatch()`, which was added in Python 3.4.  To use with `re.match()`, `^` and `$` need to be added to the beginning and end of the pattern, respectively, for 2 more bytes.

```
([^K]|K($|[^O]|O($|[^R]|R($|[^O]|O($|[^N]|N($|[^K]|K($|[^O]|O($|[^R]|R($|[^K]|K($|[^O]))))))))))*
```

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/kO7vM2/1)

Previous **incorrect** solution (see comments):

```
K|([^K]|K([^O]|O([^R]|R([^O]|O([^N]|N([^K]|K([^O]|O([^R]|R([^K]|K[^O])))))))))*
```

**Edit:** Added single K

Comment: I don't believe this matches `K`.

Comment: @orip - Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: Latest update now fails for `KKORONKORKO`

Comment: Is it fixable? Any ideas?

Comment: The starting `^` and ending `$` aren't necessary. Also, `=` and `$` aren't allowed.